# Deserialize JSON with json.NET into C# dynamic

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have following problem: I have a json file that looks like this

```
{
    "Path": {
        "FirstPath": "/1/2/text()"
    }
}
```

If I parse this JSON-File with Newtonsoft like this

```
 dynamic dyn = JObject.Parse(json);
```

or this

```
dynamic dyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

I get a dynamic object that needs to be used like this

```
dyn.Path.FirstPath.Value
```

How can I get rid of the Value stuff? All of my objects in the JSON end up being a string. I don't want to always write ".Value" at the end if it is not necessary.

Answer (score 12):

I tested this using Newtonsoft 8.0.2 and it works fine.

```
        dynamic dyn = JObject.Parse(json);

        string value = dyn.Path.FirstPath;
```

Value should equal `/1/2/text()`.

Comment: Yes but if you look closer you can see that "value" isn't a string it is from Type "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue". If you take "value" and pass it to a Method that expects a string you will get an Exception. It only works if you write "value.Value".

Comment: Replace the "var" with "string" then. I've updated my answer.