# Deserialize JSON string to Object C# using Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I want to deserialize a JSON string that I don't know its Type to an object of type `Object` and be able to access its properties using reflection.
when I used this

```
object myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\'Id\':\'1\'}");
```

the type of `myObject` is of type `JObject`and I am not able to access its properties using reflection.

is there a way to do so using Json.net or any other JSON deserializer?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object

Comment: Or this with JSON.NET: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net

Comment: @scotru I've tried the dynamic too. My point is that I need to access its properties using reflection. the generated dynamic object is also of type JObject

Comment: Your question should be answered under this link: [JSON deserialize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238194/deserialize-json-with-json-net-into-c-sharp-dynamic)

Comment: @AndreasM. I've tried the dynamic too. My point is that I need to access its properties using reflection. the generated dynamic object is also of type JObject

Comment: Hmm, still not following the difficulty here--is the question how to use reflection on dynamic objects?  If so see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631546/get-property-value-from-c-sharp-dynamic-object-by-string-reflection

Comment: @HebaGomaah have you tried to create an object that contains all properties

Comment: @scotru the question is, is there any deserializer that can convert a json string to an object just as if the type of the data is a predefined type? not to a JObject

Comment: @HebaGomaah I understand now.  Is the Json simple (attribute value pairs?)  If so I think grrrrrs answer is best.  If not maybe you could use an ExpandoObject as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906010/deserialize-dynamic-json-string-using-newtonsoft-json-net  AND https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594527/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-properties-of-an-anonymous-object-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can deserialize the object into either a `Dictionary<string,string>` or an `expandoobject` (also castable to `IDictionary<string,object>`) and then you don't need to use reflection to get at the properties, you can get them through the dictionary.

See: [Deserialize Dynamic Json string using Newtonsoft JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906010/deserialize-dynamic-json-string-using-newtonsoft-json-net)

Comment: {"Id":"1"} is just a sample. The properties can be of any type, may be of a new object

Comment: Then you'd be better off using dynamic I'd say

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't let you use reflection per-se but an ExpandoObject does let you iterate over the properties:

```
        string json = "{\'Id\':\'1\'}";
        var converter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
        dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json, converter);

        IDictionary<string, object> dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)obj;
        foreach (string key in dict.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(key);
        }
```